# Keys giving errors in Python

Tags: python, json, python-asyncio

I am trying to get the 'last_price' from my codes output. My code is:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json

#subscribe to channel
msg3 = \
    {"jsonrpc": "2.0",
     "method": "public/subscribe",
     "id": 42,
     "params": {
        "channels": ["ticker.BTC-PERPETUAL.raw"]}
    }

async def call_api3(msg3):
   async with websockets.connect('wss://testapp.deribit.com/ws/api/v2') as websocket:
       await websocket.send(msg3)
       while websocket.open:
           response = await websocket.recv()
           # do something with the notifications...
           o = json.loads(response)
           print(o['params']['data']['last_price'])

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    asyncio.ensure_future(call_api3(json.dumps(msg3)))    
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    print('closing loop')
    loop.close()
```

and my codes output is:

```
{'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'method': 'subscription', 'params': {'channel': 'ticker.BTC-PERPETUAL.raw', 'data': {'timestamp': 1574491157294, 'stats': {'volume': 873649.05224518, 'low': 6777.0, 'high': 7713.0}, 'state': 'open', 'settlement_price': 7538.95, 'open_interest': 483060328, 'min_price': 7196.97, 'max_price': 7269.3, 'mark_price': 7232.85, 'last_price': 7231.0, 'instrument_name': 'BTC-PERPETUAL', 
'index_price': 7234.32, 'funding_8h': -3.366e-05, 'current_funding': 0.0, 'best_bid_price': 7231.0, 'best_bid_amount': 269720.0, 'best_ask_price': 7231.5, 'best_ask_amount': 2490.0}}}
```

However I get a key error when just filtering down to ['params'], in fact the only key that has worked for me is ['jsonrpc'].

I am also wondering why my code gives a parse error when I remove that json.dumps... why does it need to convert it back into a string, because I will need it as on object/integer for use later?

Comment: Do you mean your print isn't working (print(o['params']['data']['last_price']))

Comment: Yes, that is not working. However print(o), or print (o['jsonrpc']) does work.

Comment: @rctrading Can you show the output of `print(o)`?

Comment: I'd like to take a look at this further, can you add msg3 into the question, it looks like i need it to run your code

Comment: @user4815162342 Please find the output of print(o) shown in my question.

Comment: @oppressionslayer This is pulling data from this API https://docs.deribit.com/v2/

I have updated the code in my question to include msg3.

Comment: I can't recreate your error from your provided output. It prints 'params' just fine.

Comment: @HaydenEastwood ummh weird... Could I get a copy of the .py file you have run?